# How to get kml file from Google Maps with url link?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I create app for smartphones using Google Maps, and I want show a road from point A to point B. How to do this?

I try use url like that:

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=50.06469,19.944788&daddr=50.064001,19.92039&dirflg=w&output=kml

but it's doesn't work (In app I get null instead kml file).

Gimer

code:

```
try {
                    /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
                    URL url = new URL("hhttps://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=50.06469,19.944788&daddr=50.064001,19.92039&dirflg=w&output=kml");

                    /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

                    /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                    /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
                    ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

                    /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                    /* Parsing has finished. */

                    /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
                    ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet =
                                                                    myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

                    /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
                    tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
                    tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "WeatherQueryError", e);
            }
```

I also try this:

```
final BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()));
```

it's work with kml files but when url is from google maps isn't.

Comment: How are you actually trying to fetch the file? What http client are you using? Give some example code of what you've tried.

Comment: I use this tutorial:
http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

Comment: Could use some someone provide a link to a working guide?